# Best way to conver ETH to a layer 2 ETH or Wrapped ETH to convert to USDC or USDT?

Tags: gas-price, fees, uniswap, usdc

I have a small amount of ETH ($100) and I want to use uniswap to convert it to USDC or USDT, but the fees of $20-$50 is a bit ridiculous. Is there a layer 2 solution that is WORKING that can convert to USDC easily without all the crazy fees? Or even a wrapped ETH token on another platform that can convert to USDC or USDT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a shortcut. If you want to convert asset A to asset B the cheapest option is usually to convert it directly.

Layer 2 is not meant for trying to save gas fees on Layer 1. Layer 2 is mostly meant for recurring transactions. You still need at least Layer 1 transactions: entering Layer 2 and exiting Layer 2. So that's already double the amount of transactions you'd normally need to perform the swap.

So either wait with your swap and hope for the fees to get lower or accept the fees.